# Adding text in a doughnut angular-chart

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart, angular-chartist.js

I have a doughnut chart in angularJS using angular-chart.js.

HTML file:

```
<div ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <canvas id="pie33" options="options" class="chart chart-doughnut chart-xs ng-isolate-scope rotate" height="120" width="240" data="pieDiskData.data" labels="pieDiskData.labels" colours="pieDiskData.colours" legend="true" ></canvas>
</div>
```

JS file:

```
angular.module('App', ["chart.js"]);
angular.module('App').controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window',

function ($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
$scope.options = {
    tooltipEvents: [],
    showTooltips: false,
    tooltipCaretSize: 0,
    scaleShowLabels: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);
    },
};

var diskDataJson = {
    "data": [100, 100, 100, 100],
        "labels": ["red", "gree","blue","white"],
        "colours": ['#FF0000', '#008000','#0000FF', '#FFFFFF']
};

$scope.pieDiskData = diskDataJson;
}]);
```

here's the fiddle:
[angularJS DoughnutChart](http://jsfiddle.net/zuhp8k5f/)

I need to add a text in the center of the graph and remove the legend and the tooltip. Please Help!

Also, I came across an angularJS directive for the same [AngularJS doughnut Directive](https://github.com/angular-directives/angular-chartjs-doughnut-directive). I want to use this directive for creating the graph. Any working jsFiddle for the same would be really appreciated.

Thanks